# Combine 4 bytes into one in Java

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Shiftcodes {
    private Map<byte[], Byte> shiftMap;

    public byte genoByte(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4) {
        return (byte) (
                  (b1 << 6)
                | (b2 << 4)
                | (b3 << 2)
                | b4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Shiftcodes shiftcodes = new Shiftcodes();
        byte b = shiftcodes.genoByte((byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/x.bin");
        fileOutputStream.write(new byte[] {b});
    }
}
```

It's assumed that the bits of each byte are all zero, except the rightmost two bits, which can be 0 or 1. So I changed the code a little:

```
public class Shiftcodes {
    private Map<byte[], Byte> shiftMap;

    public byte genoByte(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4) {
        return (byte) (
                  ((b1 & 0x11) << 6)
                | ((b2 & 0x11) << 4)
                | ((b3 & 0x11) << 2)
                | b4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Shiftcodes shiftcodes = new Shiftcodes();
        byte b = shiftcodes.genoByte((byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/x.bin");
        fileOutputStream.write(new byte[] {b});
    }
}
```

But in both cases I am getting what I expected (01110010):

```
xxd -b x.bin
0000000: 01010000                                               P
```

Why?

Comment: Because the input values are exactly the same before and after applying your `and` mask.

Comment: If it's already assumed that only the 2 rightmost bits can be nonzero, why bother with the mask at all? Do you mean instead that you can safely ignore all but the rightmost 2 bits? If so, please update your question; if not, should you instead be asserting or throwing an exception if (b1 >> 2) != 0 (or any of the others)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mistake [`hex literals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-HexNumeral) for [`binary literals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-BinaryNumeral):

```
0x11; // Hex 11, Dec 17, Bits 00010001
0b11; // Hex 3,  Dec 3,  Bits 00000011
```

Answer (score 6):

The rightmost two bits would be `0x3` not `0x11`. `0x11` is 00010001 in binary rather than 00000011.

```
return (byte) (
          ((b1 & 0x3) << 6)
        | ((b2 & 0x3) << 4)
        | ((b3 & 0x3) << 2)
        | b4);
```